# How to include on the wall a photo post though graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i use graph api to post a picture, everything is ok. The photo is right in the album.
The problem is that the picture is not mention on the wall. It's just include in the album with nothing on the wall.

I use basic code like that :

```
            $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);     
            $file = "@".realpath(PIC);  

            $result = $facebook->api(
            '/PAGE_ID/photos/',
            'post',
            array('access_token' => $access_token,
                  'type' => 'status',
                  'message' => stripslashes(MESSAGE),
                  'image' => $file
                )
            );
```

Do you know how to force the picture and the message to appear on the wall as a status?

Comment: I had the same problem. it appeared in first try but now i can not see on my wall.. trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: if you delete APPNAME_Photos album and call your code, it will appear on your wall for the first photo, but after 2nd call, it does not appear on wall.. at least i could diagnose the problem.. trying to solve out..

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround could i figure out is to get Wall Photos album's ID and post photo to that album to appear on wall..

Unfortunately there is no easier way to force it out. Here is the sample code:

```
    $result = $facebook->api('/'.$pageID.'/albums/?access_token='.$access_token, 'get' );
    $albumArr = $result['data'];
    $albumID = 0;

    for($j = 0 ; $j < sizeof($albumArr) ; $j++) {
        if ($albumArr[$j]['type'] == 'wall') {
            $albumID = $albumArr[$j]['id'];
        }
    }

    $result = $facebook->api('/'.$albumID.'/photos/', 'post' , array('access_token' => $access_token,
              'type' => 'status',
              'message' => stripslashes(MESSAGE),
              'image' => $file
            ) );
```

Comment: Default value should be "me": `$albumID = 'me';`

Comment: /me/photos will create a new album with the name of application, so may not show at your wall. but after changed to timeline, it might changed.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented this in Java and it finally worked when I requested the permissions "photo_upload" (to be able to upload to wall-album) and "user_photos" (to be able to request the list of albums).